# Javascript as client in webapp sharepoint online backend

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, webclient

I have a colleague with a strange idea , (or maybe not so strange ? :) I need your help to determine ... He wants to use JavaScript in a Web client application (in this case EPiServer CMS) to handle (crud) all the documents in the backend ( SharePoint Online ) . The problem is , I can't find any way to get a reference to 
SharePoint Online in from the JavaScript code (on aspx page on client). Is there a way ?  And more important, is this really a good approach to document handling in this solution ? There must be better approaches ?
BR/Christer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to access SharePoint Online resources from a different domain. This is usually prohibited by SharePoint as Cross-Site-Scripting. You have to authenticate yourself to SharePoint before you can use any of it. 
If you can describe your intentions more clearly, it might help to post them on https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Nils...I posted the question like this: "Is there a way to connect to SharePont Online from Web client javascript (js-code embedded in in .aspx page). How can I authenticate ? How can I access list item objects such as library documents from my client JavaScript code (if possible) ? !