# Integration with SharePoint Online

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, document

What are the options (and best practice)  to integrate a Webapp (in this case EPIServer CMS) with SharePoint/Sharepoint online as it's document backend ? EPI-SP-connector, Rest-API from C#/Javascript, Javascript or something else ?I look forward to hear your suggestions :)  /Chris

Comment: What happened to [your old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300534/javascript-as-client-in-webapp-sharepoint-online-backend)?

Comment: I posted it on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ , a little different formulated. This is a try to see my problem from another point of view.